# pandas - Find value in other column based on maxtimestamp provided by date only

Tags: python, pandas

How to fetch v2 for any given date (max timestamp). so suppose i have only date known as `2017-04-03`, then how to find v2 at max timestamp for date 2017-04-03 (`2017-04-03 16:30:00`). I know about `df.loc`

```
                       v1    v2
2017-04-03 09:15:00  35.7  35.4
2017-04-03 16:30:00  82.7  82.6
2017-04-04 09:15:00  24.3  24.2
2017-04-04 16:30:00  70.2  70.6
2017-04-28 09:15:00  31.7  31.4
2017-04-28 16:30:00  33.0  33.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can obtain the index with `df.index` and filter it with:

```
from datetime import date

df.index.date == date(2017, 4, 3)
```

which returns a list of booleans:

```
>>> df.index.date == date(2017, 4,3)
array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False])
```

Next we can obtain the maximum timestamp of these indices with:

```
>>> df.index[df.index.date == date(2017, 4,3)].max()
Timestamp('2017-04-03 16:30:00')
```

So we can use `df.loc[..]` to obtain the corresponding record with:

```
>>> df.loc[df.index[df.index.date == date(2017, 4,3)].max()]
v1    82.7
v2    82.6
Name: 2017-04-03 16:30:00, dtype: float64
```

or the corresponding value for `v2` with:

```
>>> df.loc[df.index[df.index.date == date(2017, 4,3)].max()].v2
82.6
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a column name for your time stamps, I assume it to be the first column:

```
df.newDate = df.apply(lambda x: x[0].split(' ')[0]) # create date column that contains only the date
df.DateTime = pd.to_datetime(df[0]) # create datetime object column
result = df.groupby('newDate').apply(lambda df: df.sort_values('DateTime').iloc[-1])
# Sorts each unique date by time.
```

Your result will only contain values which are the latest one for each day

Answer (score 0):

Convert your index to datetime object if you haven't already and then access max value

```
# Convert your index to datetime object
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Then,

```
df.loc['2017-04-03'].v2.max()
82.6
```

or you can try,

```
df.groupby(df.index.date).v2.max()

2017-04-03    82.6
2017-04-04    70.6
2017-04-28    33.7
Name: v2, dtype: float64
```

or more complex

```
df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.v2.max(), x.v2.idxmax()]))
# Output
             0              1
2017-04-03  82.6    2017-04-03 16:30:00
2017-04-04  70.6    2017-04-04 16:30:00
2017-04-28  33.7    2017-04-28 16:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having a datetimeindex. You can sort is and get last.

```
df.sort_index().groupby(df.index.date).last()
```

If the index is not datetime, use

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

You get

```
2017-04-03    82.6
2017-04-04    70.6
2017-04-28    33.7
```